# dataWithContentsOfURL and imageWithData take 84% of the whole loading time

Tags: objective-c, performance, uiimage, nsdata

these two lines took 40% and 42% (together 84%) of the whole loading time of my app. I tested it with *Instruments*.

```
NSData *storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:storeImageURL]; //40% whole load time
UIImage *storeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData]; //42% whole load time
```

Is there another / better way to speed up the loading time of my app? These two lines and a lot more code are in a loop wich will loop about 500 times.

**Note**
after adding "http://" to the usual "www.blah.net" it starts to be slow. Does anyone know why 7 characters (of about 30-50) in an URL slows the loading time so massively down. Before I changed it, it took 3 seconds. Now 37 seconds.

Comment: Load it asynchronously ... It's not really faster but the UI is not blocked and you can display a progress bar

Comment: @HAS did u have a sample for me? I have not been busy with caching. Each image is about 16kb.

Comment: Are you loading a fixed set of images from your own server? If so, it would most likely be a lot faster to download a single, large zip file with all of the images than downloading 500 individual images. Better yet, include them with the app. In either case of downloading, definitely do the downloading in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy These images aren't static they can switch from time to time. I load the url out of a XML and display them in a DetailView of every pin in my mapView. The DetailView get all information out of the pin wich have a custom class for that. At the end of Parsing i simply do:`MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithTitle:title subtitle:subtitle coordinate:loc description:description storeImage:storeImage]; [annotationArray addObject:placeObject];`

Comment: if you want to display this images using `UIImageView` then there is an extended version of `UIImageView` with asynchronous download, you can download its [source code from here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/LazyImageView)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your lines with these,

```
 __block NSData *storeImageData;
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //load url image into NSData
    storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:storeImageURL];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //convert data into image after completion
        UIImage *storeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];
        //do what you want to do with your image
    });

});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

For further info, see [dispatch_queue_t](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)

Comment: The problem is that my placing pins are now faster than the images. So my pins were created and and the `storedImage` is `nil`. But very positive at your code is that the images will load overall 5 times faster than before. I think the best way is to write something like: "hey there is no image wait for it, you can pass after image is loaded" or something like that. Do you have an idea?

Comment: well, you could initially load and place a dummy image, like "image-is-loading", from bundle and refresh after :)