# Browser loads images faster than ios App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, cdn

I am using the CloudFront CDN to deliver images for an mobile application.

I tested the download speed on a browser on my computer and the images (about 60 kb) appear almost instantly.

In the iOS Application however the downloads take 0.3 - 0.4 seconds.
To download the images I use a the dataWithContontentsOfURL method on a background thread.

`NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:categoricalSystemURL];`

Why does the image load  much faster in the browser? 
Is there a faster way to download images on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solusion [dataWithContentsOfURL and imageWithData take 84% of the whole loading time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301615/datawithcontentsofurl-and-imagewithdata-take-84-of-the-whole-loading-time)

Encoding Nsdata to Uiimage takes some time.